# Accessing "Parent Scope"

Tags: javascript, scope

***Disclaimer:*** I'm not sure that I'm using the correct terminology.

Given this code:

```
var sample = 'Text';
var test = function(sample) {
    console.log(sample);
};
test('Text Too');
```

I am aware that if the function parameter had a different name, the `console.log()` call would output "Text". Is there a way for the `test()` function to reference the "parent scope" variable, `sample` without changing the name of the function parameter? If so, how?

Comment: your last line is the answer. WHAT else do you want?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to do without changing the name of the function parameter.

Comment: you could but that would involve `window` object or any other object.

Comment: In general, the answer is no. If the outer scope happens to be the global scope, then you can access the variable as a property of the global object (`window` in a browser).

Comment: [Variable Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in JavaScript. If you use the same variable name in the inner scope, the outer scope variable becomes completely inaccessible to that inner scope.

*Edit:* Except, of course, when the outer scope is the global scope. Then you could use `window.sample`.

Comment: What about using this.sample?

Comment: `this` seems totally offtopic. As I understand the question, it deals with variable visibility and scopes, not object properties and function call context.

Comment: To be more precise: Yes, `this.sample` would actually work in the code provided, but only because it is assumed to be in global scope and the default context for function calls is `window`. So it's just an obfuscated way of saying "In global scope, you can use `window.sample`."

Answer (score 2):

@plbsam is right, he shouldn't have deleted his answer.

In your specific case, `this` inside a function is the context it is called in: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
var sample = 'Global var';
var test = function(sample) {
  console.log("sample: "+sample);
  console.log("this.sample: "+this.sample);
};
test('Local var');
```

---

## EDIT:

as this all depends on the scope the function is called in you can always assign `this` to a separate var in the global scope to be able to access it anywhere:

```
// this var can now be accessed inside any function as a reference to the global scope.
global = this;

var sample = 'Global';
var test = function(abc) {
  console.log("sample: "+sample);
  console.log("this.sample: "+this.sample);
  console.log("global.sample: "+global.sample);
};
test('Local');
```